# Splitting this string using javascript or ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, matlab

I have the following string:

```
Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)
```

and 1000 other similar ones that are not of identical format. I want to separate the product (the text portion), the volume (`125ML`), and the collation (`(3 * 8)`) into separate variables.

I tried with excel and with matlab to come up with a function, but have not managed to achieve the desired result. I want to come up with a clever way to do it than manually screening each one. All input appreciated.

Comment: You could find the index of the first `(`, then make a substring up to it. Then if you split that substring by spaces, you know that the quantity is the last element, and everything else is part of the name. Then you can get the weird bracket thing. --- It's a little unclean, but it'd work.

Comment: Just provide three random samples from your input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: `javascript`/`ruby`/`matlab` Which one should it be?

Comment: @EricDuminil I have environments I can implement in all. Matlab is on my local machine here with me though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, for example `^(.*)( \d+ML) +\((.*)\)`

**Explanation**

`^(.*)` Group 1 : any characters from start

`( \d+ML)` Group 2 : A space followed by a volume in digits and ML

`+\((.*)\)` Group 3 : Anything between parenthesis after at least one space

**Applied to your sample string**

Full match      `Upper and lower 2 ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)`

Group 1:        `Upper and lower 2 ranch milk`

Group 2:        `125ML`

Group 3:        `3 * 8`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SdzCl5/2/)

**Sample snippet in JavaScript**

Look at console

```js
function extractInformation(from) {
 var re = /^(.*)( \d+ML) +\((.*)\)/;
 var matches = re.exec(from);
 if(matches) {
  return {
   "title" : matches[1].trim(),
   "volume": matches[2].trim(),
   "collation": matches[3].trim(),
  }
 }
 return {};
}

console.log(extractInformation("Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)"));
console.log(extractInformation("Upper and lower 123 ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)"))
```

Comment: On the demo, each line only has 1 group. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: No each line has 3 groups. I updated regex so that title can also contain digits

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for the majority of the lines, some are completely messed up so won't fit this. Now to get the excel sheet into a ruby array and to run this on it. Many thanks again!

Comment: I had never seen regex groups until now. This is a great learning experience. Thanks for showing.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good solution but might save the day (JavaScript).

```
var str = "Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)"    
f = str.match(/\d+ML/g)[0]
//"125ML"
[x,y] = str.split(f)
//Array [ "Upper and lower ranch milk ", " (3 * 8)" ]
x
//"Upper and lower ranch milk "
y
//" (3 * 8)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you'd just need to split around some digits followed by `ML` :

```
text = "Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)"
p text.split(/\s+(\d+ML)\s+/)
# ["Upper and lower ranch milk", "125ML", "(3 * 8)"]
```

The [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) argument usually isn't returned in the list, except if you define a group (with `()` inside the regex).

To parse your Excel file, it might be much easier to export the spreadsheet as a CSV file and parse it with the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: I'm getting an error in the ruby code that split is an undefined method

Comment: @theoneinskane: `split` has been a String method for decades. On which object do you try to use it?

Comment: I know, I'm trying to apply it to the row of the CSV file like this `require 'csv'

   CSV.foreach('prodName.csv') do |row|
        puts row.split(/\s+(\d+ML)\s+/)
    end`

Comment: @theoneinskane: A csv row isn't a string. You probably want a cell

Answer (score 1):

```
"Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)".partition(/\d+ML/)
# => ["Upper and lower ranch milk ", "125ML", " (3 * 8)"]

"Upper and lower ranch milk 125ML (3 * 8)".partition(/\d+ML/).map(&:strip)
# => ["Upper and lower ranch milk", "125ML", "(3 * 8)"]
```